# Variable JSON request template for AWS APIGW x-amazon-apigateway-integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am creating an AWS **API Gateway** via an **openapi.json** file. It will act as a pass through where if authorized, will pass the request to a web service within the corp network.
The web service that the API Gateway will connect to has a variable type input json format. Something like this:

If type is individual:

```
{
  "type" : "INDIVIDUAL" ,
  "params" : {
    "name" : "John",
    "age" : "33" , 
    "gender" : "M"
  }
}
```

if type is organization

```
{
  "type" : "ORGANIZATION" ,
  "params" : {
    "name" : "Tesla Motors",
    "type" : "corporation" , 
    "location" : "Palo Alto CA"
  }
}
```

How do I set this in the requestTemplates section of x-amazon-apigateway-integration.

I did my due diligence and researched on the documentation. All I found was this -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration-requestTemplates.html. Found nothing specifying how to setup this scenario.